# generate random negative to positive float numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, floating-point, negative-number

How can I produce random values between -0.01 and 0.01? That does not work:

```
rand()-(0.01);
```

And many others I found in the internet don't work. It seems very easy but I am about to go crazy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html):

> In general, you can generate N random numbers in the interval (a,b)
> with the formula:
>
> `r = a + (b-a).*rand(N,1)`

In your partuclar case, if you wish to generate `10` random numbers in the interval `(-0.01, 0.01)` you would do:

```
r = -0.01 + (0.01-(-0.01)).*rand(10,1)
```

which gives:

```
r =

    0.0081
   -0.0075
    0.0083
    0.0026
   -0.0080
   -0.0044
    0.0009
    0.0092
    0.0093
   -0.0068
```

Answer (score 2):

`(2*rand() - 1) / 100.0` should do the job. It is a particular case of the more general answer by @Cebri.

- `rand(): [0, 1]`
- `2*rand(): [0, 2]`
- `2*rand()-1: [-1, 1]`
- `(2*rand()-1)/100: [-0.01, 0.01]`